# Исключить документы с одинаковыми полями, mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Пусть есть модель (mongoengine):

```
class A(Document):
    a = IntField()
    b = IntField()
    c = IntField()
```

Список документов в базе:

```
{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1 }
{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':2 }
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1 }
```

Запрос: `A.objects()`; получаем все документы.

Но как получить только такие документы?

```
{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1 }
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1 }
```

Т.е. нужно исключить те документы, у которых поля `a` и `b` совпадают с полями `a` и `b` какого-либо другого документа, выбранного ранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если уникальным должно быть значение только одного поля,
то всё элементарно — используйте `distinct`.

Если уникальным должно быть некое множество полей,
тогда нужно использовать `aggregate` и в логике функции агрегации
описать, что должно оставаться первое значение (или ещё какое-то, в соответствии с вашей задачей).

Подробно как это делается описано здесь:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103534/ (англ.)